# Python readline positioning my print underneath instead of next to

Tags: python, readline

so i'd like to get the text saying Yuppie or Noup to the right side of the readline print and I can't quite figure out slicing and spacing yet. This task was about removing all special characters from a pre-existing .txt file, anyway heres the code:

```
import string
bringthe = open("ape.txt","r")
readthe = bringthe.readline()

invalid_char = set(string.punctuation)
while readthe:
    readthe = readthe[:-1]
    
    readthe = bringthe.readline()
    if any(poop in invalid_char for poop in readthe):
        print(readthe,'yuppie')
    else:
        print(readthe,'nouppie')
```

And this is what the outcome looks like, all the answers in the wrong position:

```
no2no123non4 

 nouppie

noq234n5ioqw#%

 yuppie

%#""SGMSGSER

 yuppie

doghdp5234

 nouppie

sg,dermoepm

 yuppie

43453-frgsd

 yuppie

hsth()))

 yuppie

bmepm35wae

 nouppie

vmopaem2234+0+

 yuppie

gsdm12313

 nouppie

bbrbwb55be3"?"#?

 yuppie

"?"#%#"!%#"&"?%%"?#?#"?"

 yuppie

retrte#%#?%

 yuppie

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxy  nouppie
 nouppie
```

Comment: So you want it such that the first line says "43453-frgsd yuppie" and so on? `print()` has an `end`-keyword that is a newline by default, so to keep printing on the same line, use `print(readthe, 'yuppie', end=' ')`.

Comment: When you do ```readline```, it comes with a ```\n``` character. You can just remove it by ```strip("\n")```

Comment: Thank you, found these both helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readline()` function is keeping the newline at the end, you can remove it with `rstrip()`:

```
readthe = bringthe.readline().rstrip()
```